# Adblock/uBlock - don't apply rule in iframe

Tags: adblock, ublock-origin, ublock

I want to block certain elements on `google.com` but only if the current page is under the `google.com` domain.

Specifically, I do not want the filter to be applied to `google.com` iframes on other pages (this is the case with captchas - it's a `google.com` iframe).

Is this possible?

Comment: What platform, what browser

Comment: 1) why should that matter??? 2) I want this to be cross-platform, cross-browser